# How to recover data from a damaged or bad DVD?

Tags: dvd, data-recovery

I have many data DVDs these were working fine some days back.

But now I am having problems reading the data of these DVDs. I have tried them on different drives but no luck. It seems that they are damaged now.

When I insert these DVDs into drive, drive keep on reading and reading.

Any suggestions How to recover data from these DVDs?

Comment: @studiohack: Thanks for reopen the question. But as one hour has gone it seems that it is very difficult to get any answer now.

Comment: actually, since I edited it, it "bumped" it to the top of the page... updates to the question (including edits or answers) bump it to the front page... Welcome to Super User! :)

Answer (score 4):

If the disc is damaged where the laser cannot read the data, no software will recover the data, you will have to repair the damage to the disc by polishing it or carefully filling deep scratches with clear nail polish or other suitable ultra clear filler. If the damage is to the actual reflective surface that stores the data, there is no recovery possible.

Disc polishers will not repair deep scratches.

Comment: Note that you might be able to read areas of the disk without scratches by using recovery software. Also note that any damage to the reflective layer (the (non-transparent) stuff that the text label is printed on) means that part of the disk's data can never be recovered, even with polishing and filling.

Comment: The label side is not the reflective coating on DVD's, you're thinking of CD-R's.  On a recordable DVD it's label, polycarbonate, reflective layer, then more polycarbonate.  On a CD-R it's just a label/reflective layer stuck to a single piece of polycarbonate.

Answer (score 3):

Wd-40 always works for me. Clean it with wd-40, then water. Then you should be good to go. It rarely fails!!

Comment: RARELY?! What about when it does fail?

Comment: Real genius!!!!

Answer (score 3):

On some optical drives, the hardware will have a long timeout on read error which the software can not override. It effectively makes the recovery impossible. Unstoppable Copier works better in hard drive recovery use cases. It may work on some hardware for data recovery, but for optical drive data recovery, the try the [free CD Recovery Tool](http://web.archive.org/web/20141215213241/http://www.oemailrecovery.com/cd_recovery.html) instead. You, unfortunately, have to install on your Windows PC, but I am currently on 500MB of 1,000GB where Unstoppable Copier failed to continue at 333MB.

Comment: Good tip about the drive timeout, thanks! And not sure why you linked through archive.org, but their website is still live http://www.oemailrecovery.com/cd_recovery.html

Answer (score 1):

At least I was able to read damaged part from DVD-Video, which player didn't play at all with [Unstoppable Copier](http://www.roadkil.net/program.php?ProgramID=29). It will not repair disc,  but can save data

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it, do it your self or have someone else do it.

If you are going to do it your self you can pick up a DVD resurfacer from any of the big box retail stores that sells dvds. They will usually have a liquid you put on the disk and it then polishes the surface. I have had both good luck and bad luck with this.

The other option, which may or may not be available in your area, is go check with your local DVD Rental Store, very frequently they will own a commercial disk resurfacer. I had one in my local town that would do it for $5. Try both chain stores and locally owned ones to see if they will do it for you.